# Change a background image of a div on click

Tags: javascript

Okay, I think my head is being dense. But I cant seem to get this to work. I'm doing a website for a photographer, and he wants to be able to let a user change the frame that they would like from a choice of 3. Easiest way I thought to do this was to create a div, and then have it change class based on a button click. So it would change the background image. However I cant get it to do this. Any ideas would be well received, as I'm guessing theres probably a javascript version that does it quicker and easier.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Untitled</title>
<style>
#pictureframe {
width:200px;
height:200px;
}

.wooden {
background-image:url(frame.png);
}

.plain {
background-image:url(clear.png);
}

.black {
background-image:url(black.png);
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="pictureframe">
</div>

<div style="height:20px;border:1px solid #617779;width:90px;text-align:center;background-color:white;" onclick = "pictureframe.style.className = 'wooden'">Make it wood</div>
<br>
<div style="height:20px;border:1px solid #617779;width:90px;text-align:center;background-color:white;" onclick = "pictureframe.style.className = 'clear'">Make it Frameless</div>
<br>
<div style="height:20px;border:1px solid #617779;width:90px;text-align:center;background-color:white;" onclick = "pictureframe.style.className = 'wooden'">Make it Black Bezel</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not

```
pictureframe.style.className = ...
```

but

```
pictureframe.className = ...
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/HH8Sy/)

Comment: This worked perfectly, thanks for this. I'm a newbie to javascript and only just learning the codes to make it work, much appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

`className` is not part of the `style` object in the DOM element, but a direct property:

```
document.getElementById("pictureframe").className = 'wooden';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
onclick ="pictureframe.className = 'wooden'"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use some other class for style, than you probably need to go with something like this:

```
function replaceClass(className) {
    $('#pictureframe').removeClass('plain black wooden');
    return $('#pictureframe').addClass(className);
}​
```

This way you can keep class with styles http://jsfiddle.net/NjTea/5/

Comment: I can sort of see this, but how would i run this in an example? Sorry total newbie to javascript.

Comment: Sure, my bad, added fiddle example

Comment: Thank you Felix, spent nearly 2 hours searching for an example, loads of background colour change, but no background image. Thats a much better way of doing it. Thank you for that. As a newbie I actually understand what you've written!